# Applying MVVM pattern in a QtQuick

Tags: qt, mvvm, qt-quick

How can i apply MVVM pattern in QtQuick applications?

Can anybody give me any sample (simple) code?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[With a C++ ViewModel](https://bitbucket.org/AntyaDev/qtquickmvvmexample/overview)

I know someone has done the same thing with a QML ViewModel and bi-directional binding for the text element for example.

Bi-directional binding is done through the binding of the text property to the viewmodel property. Then, add a Binding node to bind the viewmodel property to the text property of the textinput.