# What's a good MV* pattern for Qt application?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, mvvm, mvp

By Qt application, I mean a C++ application with Qt GUI. I used MVP for Android project and Winform, MVC for ASP.NET MVC of course, and MVVM for WPF/Silverlight/Javascript. But now, as I need to start learning Qt, what is a MV* pattern good for Qt application?

Comment: Do you use widgets or QtQuick?

Comment: I've blogged a PyQt implementation of the Humble Dialog Box pattern. It can easily be converted to regular C++ Qt, and used as the basis for a full MVP implementation (when "business logic" is added): http://duganchen.ca/a-humble-dialog-implementation-in-pyqt/

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533859/applying-mvvm-pattern-in-a-qtquick